# To make odd position in list go forward for one step

Tags: python-3.x

I found this code from stackoverflow ... and wondering how can I move index position that I want.
I tried to use for loop and [::1]. And by making, len(a)*[0]...I couldn't make it.

Is there any way to fix items on its position in list?

Second, without using method below, is there another way to reorder items in list?
'''
mylist=['a','b','c','d','e']
myorder=[3,2,0,1,4]
'''

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = ((a+a[:0:-1])*len(a))[::len(a)][:len(a)]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4] <=b
[7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4] <= the result i want
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
orderedList = sorted(someList)
reversedOrderedList = orderedList[::-1]
finalList = []
for i in range(len(someList)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        finalList.append(reversedOrderedList[i//2])
    else:
        finalList.append(orderedList[i//2])
print(finalList)
```

output:

`[7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]`

if so, you can write it in shorter way (without `reversedOrderedList`):

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
orderedList = sorted(someList)
finalList = []
for i in range(len(someList)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        finalList.append(orderedList[-1-i//2])
    else:
        finalList.append(orderedList[i//2])
print(finalList)
```

and from here you can write it without `if` statement:

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
orderedList = sorted(someList)
for i in range(len(someList)):
    finalList.append(orderedList[((-1)**(i%2+1)-1)//2 + ((- 1)**(i%2+1))*(i//2)])
print(finalList)
```

It is not pretty but after that you can easily write a `generator`.

Answer (score 0):

Zip the list with its reversed version, flatten it and take the first half:

```
from itertools import chain
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

b = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a[::-1], a)))
print(b[:len(b) // 2])
```

Output

```
[7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```